# How much should I ask as an Atlassian administrator?

Tags: software-industry, salary, software, europe

could you please help me figure out my salary? For me, it is not easy to figure the salary range for this one, since not a lot of people I know work in this area so I have little to compare with.

I am working in Europe in IT an Atlassian Administrator. This means that I administer a portfolio of applications (Jira, Confluence, Crowd,...) ranging from installing, upgrading, configuring, troubleshooting, consulting with users and doing a business analysis. I also have a intermediate knowledge of Linux, PostgreSQL and other parts of the application needed and I hold three certifications that basically help companies get discounts on Atlassian software licenses.

I have 4 years of experience in the area professionally, and 3 years of experience in the area as a hobbyist.

What would be a good hourly / MD rate to ask?

Thank you for any advice you might have. :)

Comment: Europe is a big place and has big differences in salaries....

Comment: I have also worked heavily with niche platforms/systems from specific vendors. You might try to reach out to Atlassian community directly. In other words, find others who do the same thing and talk about it. Alternatively, if you know folks at Atlassian itself, they would be an excellent resource for information _and_ leads. I've actually found a great job that way (just reaching out to a vendor I've extensively worked with and asked if they knew of openings).

Comment: @teego1967 thanks - that's a good idea with Atlassian community!

Answer (score 0):

We can't tell you what you are worth. If there are few people in your very niche field to compare yourself against to work out a fair price, then you will have to compare yourself against more generic roles - similar levels of responsibility and skill, but without the attachment to a specific vendor.